# Anchoring a text to the middle of a page

Tags: html, css

I've searched online for the answer to this question and I know it is possible to do this, but I just can't figure it out with what's out there.

Background: I'm creating a frequently asked questions segment where one can click the question and be directed to the answer on the same page. I also have the questions split into categories.

Although I have been able to achieve this with basic href concepts, I would like for the answer to the question to be displayed on the middle of the page and not right below of the margin of the top of the page once the user clicks the questions that's anchored.

Hopefully, I was able to paint a somewhat picture of what I mean. Now, I will show you what I have in terms of syntax.

I definitely do believe there are multiple ways in which I could've created the code using style, class, or other attributes, but I don't hold a strong coding background :(. Therefore, I went with what I was able to pick up from W3School stuff XD.

If someone can help me out, I'd very much appreciate it since it'd make the FAQ section a lot cooler to use.

Here are images explaining the scenario a little better as well.

[Question Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmbom.png)
[Answer Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpIk0.png)

```
         <p> 
         <strong>Color Questions</strong>
         <br/>
         <a href="#A">What is the door's color?</a>
         <br />
         <a href="#B">What is the window's color?</a>
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>Shape Questions</strong>
         <br/>
         <a href="#C">What is the shape of a ball?</a>
         <br/>
         <a href="#D">What is the shape of a box?</a>
         </p>
         <h3>Answers</h3>
         <p>
         <strong>Color Questions</strong>
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>
         <a id="A"></a>What is the door's color?
         </strong>
         <br />The door's color is blue. 
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>
         <a id="B"></a>What is the window's color?</strong>
         <br />The windows's color is red. 
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>
         Shape Questions</strong>
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>
         <a id="C"></a>What is the shape of a ball?
         </strong>
         <br />A ball has the shape of a sphere.  
         </p>
         <p>
         <strong>
         <a id="D"></a>What is the shape of a box?
         </strong>
         <br />A box has the shape of a cube. 
         </p>
```

Comment: JS will make this easier. Out of curiosity, what makes you think landing on the middle of the page is better? I'm not sure that's standard from a UX point of view -- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/in-page-links/ -- 'Confirm the Jump'

Comment: @ovokuro Well, I do agree it'd be a stretch to set the answers in the "middle." However, I do would like to add some sort of padding between the answer and the top of the margin. I am certain this would be more visually ergonomic. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score -3):

if you want to put your text in middle you can use `<center>`and put your text in this tag but it is obsolete right now,there are better methods to do this.you can use `margin` and `padding`and set your text in great position also you can use `position`.check the [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) for more details.its helpful.

Comment: The question is asking about the scroll. When you link to an element ID it scrolls that element to the top of the window, not the center.